# Where can I buy this speeder bike?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I am looking for this specific model since quite a while, but was unable to find it ingame. A google search turned up a lot of stuff from SWG, but I couldn't find a location for SWTOR.

[image: Visual Artifact]

Comment: Wish you had a better graphics card ;)

Comment: @sorean I have a 7850, which is just fine. The pixelation comes from resizing the image so it fits better.Not many have those speeders and it was a quick screenshot. I made it bigger so it is better visible. I play the game on the highest settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the [JA-3](http://dulfy.net/2012/05/29/complete-high-res-catalog-of-all-swtor-speeders/#ja3speeder).

[image]

Unfortunately there's no way to acquire that one if you don't already have it. It was given as a reward during the Join the Battle subscription drive last fall, so the only way to have it is to have been a subscriber at the end of October 2013.

Note that the Hyrotii Racer uses the same model with an orange & black color scheme, and can be found (rarely, I believe) in Freelancer & Contractor's Bounty Packs. The Hyrotii Scrapper uses the same model with a grey & sky blue color scheme, and can supposedly be found from seeker droid spots if you're (very) lucky.

Edit: Freelancer & Contractor's Bounty Packs are purchased with cartel coins; they can also be purchased from other players (including via the GTN), as can the speeders that come out of them. Seeker droids are acquired in a level 53 mission on Coruscant or Dromund Kaas, and basically let you "dig" for buried treasure just about anywhere with a 15 second cooldown. You can *very* rarely get something valuable like a speeder this way.

Comment: Just to clarify: What are Bounty Packs? Can they only be bought in the store? And what are Seeker Droid spots? Sorry, but I am relatively new to the game. I don't care too much about the colors, the model is what I am after, since it is the speeder bike from the movies.

Comment: @Assylum Updated with info on packs & seeker droids.

Comment: Just so you know, I got both blue mounts via the Seeker Droid Spots now and working on the pleasure speeder :P. But yeah, the Explorer is pretty close and resembles the one from Episode V pretty good.